# Could A Taoist Split Movement?

Tags: ghost-stories

One of the Red Taoists abilities allows him to move twice. Could that taoist possibly split their movement?

- Move Once (1)
- Exorcise or Use Village Tile
- Move Again (2)

Similarly, can any taoist pick the order in which they do their actions? For example, can a taoist attack first and move second or does the optional move *have* to be taken first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move always happens before your action. The red power doesn't affect this; it only makes the move part more powerful.

From the rules:

> After the Yin phase is done, the player plays the role of his Taoist, according to the
>   following sequence:
>
> 1) Move (optional)
>
> 2) Request help from a villager OR attempt an exorcism